# Mappings, Serge Lange Basic mathematics. (f.g)^3 = I

Tags: functions, proof-explanation, closed-map

I have been struggling with this question for quite a time now:

Let $f,g$ be mappings of a set $S$ into itself. Assume that $f^2 = g^2 = I$ and that $f \circ g = g \circ f$. Prove that $(f \circ g)^2=I$. Prove that $(f \circ g)^3=I$.

I have proved $(f \circ g)^2 = I$:
$$
(f \circ g) \circ (f \circ g)= (f \circ g)^2 = (f^2 \circ g^2)=I \circ g^2= I \circ I = I.
$$

But when trying to prove that $(f \circ g)^3=I$ it seems impossible I have tried all I can. Is it even true?

Comment: If you cannot prove it then you could look for a counter-example.  Perhaps consider $S=\{0,1\}$ and $f(s)=s$ with $g(s)=1-s$

Comment: Your proof of $(f \circ g)^2 = I$ might be better as $(f \circ g)^2=f \circ g \circ f \circ g=f \circ f \circ g \circ g = I^2=I$ to make the use of $f \circ g = g \circ f$ explicit.  Something similar would show $(f \circ g)^3=(f \circ g)$

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following counterexample, with transposition permutations $f = (1,2)$ and $g = (3,4)$ in $S_4$ (these are bijections on $\{1,2,3,4\}$ that just swap the pair of elements specified and leave other elements unchanged). Then $f^2 = g^2 = I$ and $f\circ g = g\circ f$ but what is $(f\circ g)^3$?